# How can I see messages I send in Mail 5's Conversation View?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I love Mail 5's new Conversation View. But, I don't like that it only shows messages sent **to** me, and doesn't show the messages **I send**.

Is there a way to show both messages I receive and messages I send in Conversation View?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Mail-> Preferences-> Viewing and check `Include related messages` (under View conversations: at the bottom).

This will show "related messages", which (as far as I can tell) means messages that you send in the same conversation.

[image]

Comment: This can also be turned on and off using the "Show Related Messages" item in the View menu

Comment: What an utterly bizarre default option on the part of Apple. -1